# How to search for 2 key words from files in a directory and print their filename if it occurs more than once

Tags: grep, duplicates, find

I am trying to grep or find for 2 specific words in each file in a directory. And then If i find more than one file found with such a combination - only then I should print those file names to a CSV file.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
find /dir/test -type f -printf "%f\n" | xargs grep -r -l -e 'ABCD1' -e 'ABCD2' > log1.csv
```

But this will provide all file names that have "ABCD1" and "ABCD2". In other words, this command will print the filename even if there is only one file that has this combo.

I will need to grep the entire directory for those 2 words and both words MUST be in more than one file if it has to write the filenames to CSV. I should also be able to include sub directories

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: so, there should be a least 2 filenames found to be printed into csv?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: and why the title says *find **duplicates** in a directory*? what duplicates? Also, elaborate should it find both of 2 patterns or one of them would be enough?

Comment: You are right - it is really not duplicates. I will change the heading accordingly (if that is allowed). I will need to grep the entire directory for those 2 words and both words MUST be in more than one file if it has to write the filenames to CSV. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ok, please update your question with your last comment. One more nuance: should subdirectories be considered during search?

Comment: Updated the question as required. And yes - subdirectories as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**find** + GNU **grep** solution:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qPz 'ABCD1[\s\S]*ABCD2|ABCD2[\s\S]*ABCD1' {} \; -printf "%f\n" \
| tee /tmp/flist | [[ $(wc -l) -gt 1 ]] && cat /tmp/flist > log1.csv
```

---

Alternative way:

```
grep -lr 'ABCD2' /dir/test/* | xargs grep -l 'ABCD1' | tee /tmp/flist \
| [[ $(wc -l) -gt 1 ]] && sed 's/.*\/\([^\/]*\)$/\1/' /tmp/flist > log1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks - it says "grep: The -P and -z options cannot be combined". This may be something related to my settings. But not sure!

Comment: @Fkhader, check my additional approach